# Can I use LIMIT with a variable?

Tags: apache-pig

The examples of LIMIT I see in the documentation tend to be like:

```
B = LIMIT A 3;
```

I would simply like to be able to use a variable (such as the count of the number of elements in another relation).

```
g_all = GROUP foo all;
count_foo = foreach g_all generate COUNT(foo.bar);
B = LIMIT A count_foo;
```

I realize the above does not work but I am trying to show what I am trying for. As far as I can tell, I don't think I can do what I want.

If I passed in a parameter to the script I think I can do this:

```
B = LIMIT A $PASSED_IN_PARAM;
```

I would like to be able to create a value internally rather than passing one in.

Answer (score 0):

This comes right from the version 11 documentation but I am not sure why this works:

```
a = load 'a.txt';
b = group a all;
c = foreach b generate COUNT(a) as sum;
d = order a by $0;
e = limit d c.sum/100;
```

The question I still have is why c.sum can be used except if you have a relation with one row it can be treated a variable sort of?